# integrating IBM WAS7 with eclipse

Tags: language-agnostic

I have IBM's WAS 7.0 and want to design applications and deploy them on the server. How do i integrate WAS with eclipse. I mean is there a plug-in for eclipse? I have been unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MyEclipseIDE Blue.

http://www.myeclipseide.com/blue.php

Comment: thanks for the help.but my project stipulates that i should eclipse for developing projects

Comment: MyEclipseIDE is Eclipse.  It's just a supported package of open source plugins for Eclipse.  They actually contribute to several open source plugins.  It's not free, but it's inexpensive, and you don't have to mess with trying to go out and find all the plugins yourself and try to figure out which versions are compatible with other plugins, etc.